# How to fix type error when using TableAdapter.Insert

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to save a record in a table in a dataset, viewed in a datagridview. Ive had no problems doing this when ive bound textboxes to each column/field in the table in the datagridview, however i need the textbox bindings to be free to use in other ways, and i also want to output the full contents of a listview to one of the columns/fields. Im trying to do this using the .insert command. However, it expects some of the fields to be integers. Any help please?

Im using vb.net and MS Access.

```
Private Sub SaveRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveRecord.Click
    Dim products As String = ListView1.ToString()
    TblSalesTableAdapter.Insert(Label7.Text, TextBox2.Text, ComboBox1.Text, products)
    TblSalesBindingSource.EndEdit()
    TblSalesTableAdapter.Update(ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblSales)
End Sub
```

Im expecting to now see the data displayed in the datagridview table under each column heading, but im getting an error as its expecting all objects in brackets to be integers, except 'status' which is expecting to be a string. Any help would be much appreciated as im on a deadline and need this completed very soon for my A Level in Computing. Thanks :)

Comment: If it expects `Integers` then pass `Integers`. It's that simple If you're saying, without actually saying, that the user may enter data into those controls that cannot be converted to an `Integer` then you need to validate the data before you use it.

Comment: I can't tell the datatype of the columns you are using to define your table. The content must match the type. If the column is defined as integer and you pass "a", it wont insert correctly. It is also important to ensure that the interaction with the db was OK by coding a try/catch block and to use parameters.

Comment: I had to re add my data source after changing the data types in access, I had a a felling that was why! Cheers for your help! While in here any idea how to reset the contents of a list view without removing the columns too? Thanks

Comment: Use `LV.Items.Clear` instead of `LV.Clear`? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeah that’s it cheers! Every time I ask I end up figuring it out before I see the replies but cheers for your help it’s much appreciated!